# Pre-1950s book about a man trying to get past a machine with long arms

Tags: story-identification, books, artificial-intelligence

- There is a machine inside a cave which has long arms and is very alert
- There is a man trying to get past the machine without being killed
- The book was most likely written pre 1950s

Comment: And this is a whole book, not a short story? Is the cave on Earth? Does the man get past the machine in the end?

Comment: Is the man trying to get into the cave, is he trying to get out of the cave, or is he trying to get from one part of the cave to another?

Comment: I can't help feeling I've seen this cover. Were the arms flexible like tentacles, but made from segmented metal? A bit like [Dr. Octopus' arms](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&q=dr+octopus) but with longer segments?

Comment: The Cyclops section of *The Odyssey* fits pretty well.  Definitely a pre-1950 story!

Answer (score 3):

This is a longshot... *The Sixth Palace* by Robert Silverberg. The machine is a robot guarding treasures. To get past it you have to answer its questions, but up till now nobody has given it the answers it wants. (If this is not the answer, I still recommend the story!)

Answer (score 3):

bowles: I don't know if you are on-site any more, but this sounds like Walter M. Miller's short story *It Takes A Thief* aka *Big Joe And The Nth Generation*, 1952. The MC is a barbaric Martian thief who is paid to enter the Cavern of the Ancients & steal the secret information hidden there; in order to reach his goal he must pass the monster Big Joe (which the reader recognizes as a robot). Big Joe has been programmed to kill anyone who would plunder the cavern, which contains equipment which will revitalize the rapidly thinning Martian atmosphere. The MC, beginning to understand the situation, convinces Big Joe he is there to help & thus begins the first step in the training necessary to operate the equipment.